# Does initializing an array from a set have a complexity and if so what is it?

Tags: swift, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Swift: Option 1

```
var dictionaryWithoutDuplicates = [Int: Int]()
for item in arrayWithDuplicates {
   if dictionaryWithoutDuplicates[item] == nil {
      dictionaryWithoutDuplicates[item] = 1
   }
}
print(dictionaryWithoutDuplicates.keys)
// [1,2,3,4]
```

Option 2

```
let arrayWithDuplicates = [1,2,3,3,2,4,1]
let arrayWithoutDuplicates = Array(Set(arrayWithDuplicates))
print(arrayWithoutDuplicates)
// [1,2,3,4]
```

For the first option there might be a more elegant way to do it but that's not my point, I just wanted to show an example that has a complexity of n.
Both options return an array without duplicates. Since the first option has a complexity of O(n), I was wondering if the second option even has a complexity and if so what is it?

Comment: Interesting, when I run your Options 2 code it prints the values in a different order each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is pretty much exactly what `Set` does. A `Set<T>` is pretty much just a `[T: Void]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<T, Void>`).

Both examples have `O(arrayWithDuplicates.count)` time and space complexity.